# Finding $n>2$ such that $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ are in arithmetico-geometric progression and $\left(1-x^3\right)^n=\sum_{r=0}^na_rx^r(1-x)^{3n-2r}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

This is the strangest, mind-boggling question I came across while doing binomial theorem.

> Let
> $$\displaystyle\left(1-x^3\right)^n=\sum_{r=0}^na_rx^r(1-x)^{3n-2r},\quad n\gt2$$
> then find the value if $n$ so that $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are in A. G. P.

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ4fD.jpg))

Sorry but i have absolutely no clue of solving it.
max i did was to expand the stuff inside the summation but it made things worse by bringing in two summations. I had aimed at comparing coefficients. 
can someone help me out ? hints appreciated.

** AGP = arithmetico geometric progression

** problem encountered in my JEE coaching study material

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: It would be nice to include where you encountered this question and, in particular, what [A. G. P.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence) means.

Comment: Comparing coefficients sounds right, but I don't know that you have to multiply it all out.  For example, the leading coefficient on the left -hand side is $(-1)^n$ and the leading coefficient on the right-hand side is $a_0(-1)^{3n}$ so $a_0=1$.  See if you can work out the next few in a similar way.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, any three numbers can be fit to an AGP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing both sides by $(1-x)^{3n}$ shows that the equation is equivalent to
$$
\left(1+\frac{3x}{(1-x)^2}\right)^n=\sum_{r=0}^na_r\left(\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\right)^r\tag1
$$
Set $u=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$, then we have
$$
\left(1+3u\right)^n=\sum_{r=0}^na_ru^r\tag2
$$
So $a_r=3^r\binom{n}{r}$, as ZAhmed computed.

---

Suppose that $3\binom{n}{1},9\binom{n}{2},27\binom{n}{3}$ are in an[Arithmetico-Geometric Progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence)
$$
a_0,a_0(1+\Delta)\mathrm{R},a_0(1+2\Delta)R^2\tag3
$$
Then
$$
a_0=3n\tag4
$$
and
$$
\frac{1+2\Delta+\Delta^2}{1+2\Delta}=\frac{\binom{n}{2}^2}{\binom{n}{1}\binom{n}{3}}=\frac32\frac{n-1}{n-2}\tag5
$$
Let $\lambda=\frac32\frac{n-1}{n-2}-1$ and then
$$
\Delta=\lambda+\sqrt{\lambda(\lambda+1)}\tag6
$$
The ratio of the first two terms is
$$
(1+\Delta)\mathrm{R}=\frac{9\binom{n}{2}}{3\binom{n}{1}}=\frac32(n-1)\tag7
$$
Therefore,
$$
R=\frac{3(n-1)}{2(1+\Delta)}\tag8
$$

---

**Examples**

These can be fit to an AGP for any $n\gt2$:

For $n=3$, we get
$$
a_0=9,\Delta=2+\sqrt6,\mathrm{R}=\frac3{3+\sqrt6}\tag{Ex3}
$$
For $n=4$, we get
$$
a_0=12,\Delta=\frac{5+3\sqrt5}4,R=\frac6{3+\sqrt5}\tag{Ex4}
$$
For $n=5$, we get
$$
a_0=15,\Delta=1+\sqrt2,R=\frac6{2+\sqrt2}\tag{Ex5}
$$
For $n=6$, we get
$$
a_0=18,\Delta=\frac{7+\sqrt{105}}8,R=\frac{60}{15+\sqrt{105}}\tag{Ex6}
$$
For $n=7$, we get
$$
a_0=21,\Delta=2,R=3\tag{Ex7}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us find out $A_r$ by rearranging both the sides as
$$(1-x^3)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{n} A_r x^r(1-x)^{3n-3r} \implies\left(1+3\left(\frac{x}{1-x)^2}\right)\right)^n =\sum_{r=0}^{n}A_r \left(\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\right)^r $$
$$\implies (1+3y)^n=\sum_{r-0}^{n} A_r y^r \implies \sum_{r=0}^{n} {n \choose r} 3^r y^r=\sum_{r=0}^{n} A_r y^r \implies A_r=3^r{n \choose r}$$
If $A_1,A_2,A_3$  form an AGP, then ${n \choose 1}, {n \choose 2}, {n\choose3}$ should be in AP
$$\implies 6n(n-1)=6n+ n(n^2-3n+2) \implies n^3-9n+14 \implies n=2,7$$
$n=7$ is acceptable.

Comment: Yes, I have edited my answer one should get $n=7$.

Comment: technically as robjohn points, we can have infinite n values giving infinite AGP's but since it was JEE integer type question, 7 is correct !

Answer (score 0):

We'll start with writing $(1-x^3)^n$ as a sum :$$(1-x^3)^n = \sum_{r=0}^{n} (-1)^r (x)^{3r}=\sum_{r=0}^{n} a_r x^r\frac{(1-x)^{3n}}{(1-x)^{2r}}$$ Now both have equal terms. So we can actually the equate the corresponding terms. So,
$$(-1)^r x^{3r} = a_r x^r \frac{(1-x)^{3n}}{(1-x)^{2r}}$$ Now transposing the $x^r$ term to the LHS, we get :
$$(-1)^r x^{2r} = a_r \frac{(1-x)^{3n}}{(1-x)^{2r}}$$ Now, transpose the $x^{2r}$ to the RHS, we get :
$$(-1)^r = a_r \frac{(1-x)^{3n}}{x^{2r}(1-x)^{2r}}$$
$$= a_r \frac{(1-x)^{3n}}{(x^2-x)^{2r}}$$
$$\implies a_r = (-1)^r \frac{(x^2-x)^{2r}}{(1-x)^{3n}}$$
And that is the value of $a_r$. Now I guess, you can take it from here

Hope it helps

Comment: $a_r$ cannot depend ob $x$.

Comment: yes, algebrology, please note that Ar doent depend on x.